# Multiple SPI masters active at once

Tags: arm, spi, m4

I'm facing the problem when trying to get 2 SPI masters working at same time. They both have different pins(mosi, miso, sck, ss) and one is used by SD-Card and another one accelerometer. My device is nRF52832 and I have been trying to use SPI drivers from nRF52 SDK 15.2.0.

I'm not sure if they can be initialized and in use same time, but its feeling quite wrong if the program needs to init and uninit another spi instance whenever it needs to communicate with another one.

Seems that whenever one instance gets initialized the second one does not work correctly. The program does not give any error. This is my first touch to embedded systems and because of that, my skill level is the novice. I really would appreciate all the help.

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2016 - 2018, Nordic Semiconductor ASA
 *
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
 *    list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 * 2. Redistributions in binary form, except as embedded into a Nordic
 *    Semiconductor ASA integrated circuit in a product or a software update for
 *    such product, must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of
 *    conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other
 *    materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 * 3. Neither the name of Nordic Semiconductor ASA nor the names of its
 *    contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this
 *    software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * 4. This software, with or without modification, must only be used with a
 *    Nordic Semiconductor ASA integrated circuit.
 *
 * 5. Any software provided in binary form under this license must not be reverse
 *    engineered, decompiled, modified and/or disassembled.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY NORDIC SEMICONDUCTOR ASA "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS
 * OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, NONINFRINGEMENT, AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
 * DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL NORDIC SEMICONDUCTOR ASA OR CONTRIBUTORS BE
 * LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR
 * CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
 * GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)
 * HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT
 * LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT
 * OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 */
/** @file
 * @defgroup fatfs_example_main main.c
 * @{
 * @ingroup fatfs_example
 * @brief FATFS Example Application main file.
 *
 * This file contains the source code for a sample application using FAT filesystem and SD card library.
 *
 */


#include "nrf.h"
#include "bsp.h"
#include "ff.h"
#include "diskio_blkdev.h"
#include "nrf_block_dev_sdc.h"


#include "nrf_log.h"
#include "nrf_log_ctrl.h"
#include "nrf_log_default_backends.h"

#include "nrf_gpio.h"
#include "nrf_delay.h"
#include "nrf_drv_spi.h"

#define FILE_NAME   "NORDIC.TXT"
#define TEST_STRING "SD card example."

#define SDC_SCK_PIN     16  ///< SDC serial clock (SCK) pin.
#define SDC_MOSI_PIN    17  ///< SDC serial data in (DI) pin.
#define SDC_MISO_PIN    18  ///< SDC serial data out (DO) pin.
#define SDC_CS_PIN      11  ///< SDC chip select (CS) pin.

#define SDC2_SCK_PIN      5
#define SDC2_MOSI_PIN     4
#define SDC2_MISO_PIN     3
#define SDC2_CS_PIN       12

#define SPI_AC_INSTANCE 1
static const nrf_drv_spi_t spi = NRF_DRV_SPI_INSTANCE(SPI_AC_INSTANCE);


/**
 * @brief  SDC block device definition
 * */
NRF_BLOCK_DEV_SDC_DEFINE(
        m_block_dev_sdc,
        NRF_BLOCK_DEV_SDC_CONFIG(
                SDC_SECTOR_SIZE,
                APP_SDCARD_CONFIG(SDC_MOSI_PIN, SDC_MISO_PIN, SDC_SCK_PIN, SDC_CS_PIN)
         ),
         NFR_BLOCK_DEV_INFO_CONFIG("Nordic", "SDC", "1.00")
);

/**
 * @brief Function for demonstrating FAFTS usage.
 */
static void fatfs_example()
{
    static FATFS fs;
    static DIR dir;
    static FILINFO fno;
    static FIL file;

    uint32_t bytes_written;
    FRESULT ff_result;
    DSTATUS disk_state = STA_NOINIT;

    // Initialize FATFS disk I/O interface by providing the block device.
    static diskio_blkdev_t drives[] =
    {
            DISKIO_BLOCKDEV_CONFIG(NRF_BLOCKDEV_BASE_ADDR(m_block_dev_sdc, block_dev), NULL)
    };

    diskio_blockdev_register(drives, ARRAY_SIZE(drives));

    NRF_LOG_INFO("Initializing disk 0 (SDC)...");
    for (uint32_t retries = 3; retries && disk_state; --retries)
    {
        disk_state = disk_initialize(0);
    }
    if (disk_state)
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("Disk initialization failed.");
        return;
    }

    uint32_t blocks_per_mb = (1024uL * 1024uL) / m_block_dev_sdc.block_dev.p_ops->geometry(&m_block_dev_sdc.block_dev)->blk_size;
    uint32_t capacity = m_block_dev_sdc.block_dev.p_ops->geometry(&m_block_dev_sdc.block_dev)->blk_count / blocks_per_mb;
    NRF_LOG_INFO("Capacity: %d MB", capacity);

    NRF_LOG_INFO("Mounting volume...");
    ff_result = f_mount(&fs, "", 1);
    if (ff_result)
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("Mount failed.");
        return;
    }

    NRF_LOG_INFO("\r\n Listing directory: /");
    ff_result = f_opendir(&dir, "/");
    if (ff_result)
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("Directory listing failed!");
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        ff_result = f_readdir(&dir, &fno);
        if (ff_result != FR_OK)
        {
            NRF_LOG_INFO("Directory read failed.");
            return;
        }

        if (fno.fname[0])
        {
            if (fno.fattrib & AM_DIR)
            {
                NRF_LOG_RAW_INFO("   <DIR>   %s",(uint32_t)fno.fname);
            }
            else
            {
                NRF_LOG_RAW_INFO("%9lu  %s", fno.fsize, (uint32_t)fno.fname);
            }
        }
    }
    while (fno.fname[0]);
    NRF_LOG_RAW_INFO("");

    NRF_LOG_INFO("Writing to file " FILE_NAME "...");
    ff_result = f_open(&file, FILE_NAME, FA_READ | FA_WRITE | FA_OPEN_APPEND);
    if (ff_result != FR_OK)
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("Unable to open or create file: " FILE_NAME ".");
        return;
    }

    ff_result = f_write(&file, TEST_STRING, sizeof(TEST_STRING) - 1, (UINT *) &bytes_written);
    if (ff_result != FR_OK)
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("Write failed\r\n.");
    }
    else
    {
        NRF_LOG_INFO("%d bytes written.", bytes_written);
    }

    (void) f_close(&file);
    return;
}

static uint8_t       tx_buf[3];
static uint8_t       rx_buf[10];    /**< RX buffer. */

uint8_t accReadByte(uint8_t RegisterAddress)
{ 
  tx_buf[0] = 0x7F & RegisterAddress;
  tx_buf[1] = 0x80 & RegisterAddress;

  APP_ERROR_CHECK(nrf_drv_spi_transfer(&spi, tx_buf, 2, rx_buf, 1+2));
  return rx_buf[2];
}

void initAcc()
{
  //nrf_gpio_set_cfg_output(SDC2_CS_PIN);

  nrf_drv_spi_config_t spi_config = NRF_DRV_SPI_DEFAULT_CONFIG;

  spi_config.ss_pin = SDC2_CS_PIN;
  spi_config.miso_pin = SDC2_MISO_PIN;
  spi_config.mosi_pin = SDC2_MOSI_PIN;
  spi_config.sck_pin = SDC2_SCK_PIN;
  spi_config.frequency = NRF_SPI_FREQ_250K;

  APP_ERROR_CHECK(nrf_drv_spi_init(&spi, &spi_config, NULL, NULL));



}

/**
 * @brief Function for main application entry.
 */
int main(void)
{
    bsp_board_init(BSP_INIT_LEDS);

    APP_ERROR_CHECK(NRF_LOG_INIT(NULL));
    NRF_LOG_DEFAULT_BACKENDS_INIT();

    NRF_LOG_INFO("FATFS example started.");

    fatfs_example();
    initAcc();

    if ( accReadByte(0x0D) == 0x6A )
    {
      NRF_LOG_INFO("Got right whoami!");
    }


    while (true)
    {
        __WFE();
    }
}

/** @} */
```

Comment: It appears you are talking about some code you wrote, but there's no code for us to look at.

Comment: There is usually a chip select pin on the chips bus that you need to toggle to say who you are talking to.  Hardware should connect this to a GPIO or some controllers have dedicated logic.  Other wise you need a gate on the control signals.  Often, just `sck` can be gated to effectively turn on/off communications to a device.

Comment: from the datasheet it appears possible to have two separate spi busses, need to have separate gpios for each for the select pin.  are you trying to do dma (didnt look yet to see if that is supported) but if so can the part/perpheral do more than one at a time?   you using interrupts are there separate interrupts?   you have scope plots to go with the source code if/when you supply that?

Comment: I think that this problem is caused by something that I don't understand on EasyDMA. When i'm stepping thru code in debugger, the memory seems to be correctly manipulated and i just cant get dma to save reply to my buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. SD-Card and the accelerometer both have different serial bus in default.  When initialized another one first, second one failed in bus initialization and that caused nRF52832 not to get the right answer.

Comment: @ligori Can you include/highlight how you solved the issue in your code?